# Universal code to write text to .txt file?

Tags: vb.net

I have code that currently writes text to a .txt file, but tested on a different computer the user has to change the line of code `"C:\Users\Blake\Documents\test2.txt"` and create/save a .txt file named `test2`. I would like to keep my code the same, as it does work. Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
    Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\Users\owner\Documents\test2.txt" 'Sends information to test2.txt 
            If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then
                Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME)
                'File.WriteLine("wILDO THE ")
                objWriter.Write("Aircraft Make & Model: " & TextBox4.Text & ", N-number: " & TextBox3.Text)
                objWriter.Write("
Gascolator Removed & Inspected in accordance with FAA approved maintenance manual")
                objWriter.Write("

Signature _____________________________")
                objWriter.Write(" " & DateTime.Now)
                'Displays current date And time
                objWriter.Close()

                MsgBox("Log Book Entry Created")
            Else
                MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")
        End If
        Else
        ErrorProvider1.SetError(Button2, "All boxes must be checked")
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Using SpecialDirectories will work or you could add a SaveFileDialog to your project and allow the user to choose where to save the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
 Dim FILE_NAME As String =  IO.Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments,"test2.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

Documents path is available in SpecialDirectories class. You can simply do this:

```
Dim FILE_NAME As String =  My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments + "\test2.txt"
```

Comment: Message box shows "Log Book Entry Created" but I cannot find a .txt file anywhere. Kudos for a quick response!

Comment: You forgot the \ in the path.